# Counting a number of occurrences of a string between 2 strings in a text file with UNIX

Tags: unix

I have been working on this for a little while and have been unable to come to a solution.  Any help would be appreciated. I am working on a UNIX workstation and have a 30-40 meg text file that I am working with. In my real file there is hundreds of Jobs. Example of input file;

```
# misc logging data
Job 1 start  
Task  start  
Task  stop  
Task  start  
Task  stop  
Job 1 stop  
# Other misc logging data  
Job 2 start  
Task  start  
Task  stop  
Job 2 stop  
# Other misc logging data  
Job 3 start  
Task  start  
Task  stop  
Task  start  
Task  stop  
Task  start  
Task  stop  
Job 3 stop
```

My desired output is:

```
Job 1, 2 Tasks  
Job 2, 1 Tasks  
Job 3, 3 Tasks
```

Thanks again...

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/^Job .* start$/ { jobname = $2; taskcount = 0; }
     /^Task start/    { taskcount++; }
     /^Job .* stop$/  { printf "Job %s, %d Tasks\n", jobname, taskcount; }'
```

This doesn't do a lot of checking (making sure the job ending is the job that was started; checking that each started task stopped, etc.), but it does process the data you provided and give the output you required.

If the 'Other misc logging data' lines could contain stuff confused with a given job and its tasks (could match the Task start line, etc), then you have to be a bit cleverer.